# Indexing varchar column to search for first letter

Tags: mysql, index, performance, varchar, query-performance

I'm trying to optimize a legacy web-app where users can ask for a list of all records whose name starts with a given character.

The query to optimize is:

```
SELECT oggetto.id_oggetto, titolo, anno, specifiche from oggetto inner join oggetto_formato on (oggetto.id_oggetto = oggetto_formato.id_oggetto)
            where attivato=1 and oggetto.titolo like 'C%' and id_formato IN ('6', '7', '4') order by titolo LIMIT 650,50;
```

Sorry for the italian.... 
*oggetto* means item and *titolo* is title. I want to speed up the lookup on oggetto.titolo.

EXPLAIN EXTENDED tells me the following:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                           | key             | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | oggetto         | ALL   | PRIMARY                                 | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                         | 42585|   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | oggetto_formato | ref   | PRIMARY,FK_oggetto_formato_2,id_oggetto | PRIMARY         | 4       | agorateca.oggetto.id_oggetto |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index    |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

I created the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX title_initial ON item (title(2));
```

The result of EXPLAIN EXTENDED for the above query after creating the index is:

```
    +----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys                           | key             | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
    +----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | oggetto         | range | PRIMARY,iniziale_titolo                 | iniziale_titolo | 9       | NULL                         | 2880 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | oggetto_formato | ref   | PRIMARY,FK_oggetto_formato_2,id_oggetto | PRIMARY         | 4       | agorateca.oggetto.id_oggetto |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index    |
    +----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

Could anyone confirm my opinion that the index is set up correctly and is doing its job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what DBMS you are using but in general yes.  It looks like your index is doing what it is supposed to.  As a general case the optimizers can take advantage of an index in a "like" query if there are no pattern (_%[] etc) characters on the left hand side.

So this will use an index

```
oggetto.titolo like 'C%'
```

But this could not

```
oggetto.titolo like '%C'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to see how distributed the two-character combinations are.

You should run this query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(TwoChar,'All Combinations'),RowCount FROM 
(
    SELECT LEFT(titolo,2) TwoChar,COUNT(1) RowCount
    FROM oggetto GROUP BY LEFT(titolo,2) WITH ROLLUP
) A
ORDER BY RowCount;
```

Afterwards, look at the two character keys with the highest RowCount.

If you can lookup those keys fast, then all the other keys can be looked up quickly as well.

Comment: Thx for this tip, it's a nice idea and I will use it in  the future